# Rails format.html rendering partial on ajax call returns weird result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I makes my ajax function request a html dataType. I set my Rails receiver to render a partial. However, the return value that is sent back to ajax contains extra information.

This is what my partial looks like:

```
<%= @courses.each do |course| %>

<div class="content">
<h4><span data-tag="course-name"><%= course.name %></span></h4>
<span data-tag="course-number"><%= course.course_number %></span>
</div>
<div class="fui-arrow-right"></div>  

<% end %>
```

This is how it is rendered (1 Object)

```
<div class="content">
<h4><span data-tag="course-name">User Interface Design</span></h4>
<span data-tag="course-number">2143416</span>
</div>
<div class="fui-arrow-right"></div>  

[#&lt;Course id: 1, name: &quot;User Interface Design&quot;, course_number: 2143416, year: 4, semester: 1, created_at: &quot;2013-09-22 21:12:51&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2013-09-22 21:34:11&quot;&gt;]
```

This is how it is rendered (0 Object)

```
[]
```

Comment: Calling `.each` on an array returns the array, so by using the `<%=` tag, you are telling it to print the array in addition to the contents of the block. Use the non-printing `<%` instead.

Comment: Ohhhh sorry for dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to not output the embedded ruby to string

```
<%= @courses.each do |course| %>

<div class="content">
<h4><span data-tag="course-name"><%= course.name %></span></h4>
<span data-tag="course-number"><%= course.course_number %></span>
</div>
<div class="fui-arrow-right"></div>  

<% end %>
```

should become

```
<% @courses.each do |course| %>

<div class="content">
<h4><span data-tag="course-name"><%= course.name %></span></h4>
<span data-tag="course-number"><%= course.course_number %></span>
</div>
<div class="fui-arrow-right"></div>  

<% end %>
```